# BottomSheetDialogFragment fix the position of actions

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to lock the button at the bottom of the BottomSheetDialogFragment when scrolling?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your content in a ScrollView (without the Button).
You can also set `behavior_peekHeight` in your BottomSheet if you dont want it to go full screen.